# Jquery script stopping JS script from working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 JS scripts and 1 JQuery script src at the bottom of my HTML page. When I include the JQuery script, though, the code in JS script delayed.js only works for a second, then stops. All the other JS scripts work. How can I fix this?

I have tried:

- changing the order of the scripts on the HTML page
- changing the JS code in delayed.js into JQuery
- moving the JS code in delayed.js into another JS script in which JS is working
- Changing the JQuery reference (e.g. from Google APIs)

Here's the code at the bottom of my HTML page:

```
<script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
<script defer src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script defer src="assets/js/delayed.js"></script>
```

Here's the code in delayed.js. It's for changing the style of the nav item according to the specific page you're on, so as a user the page you're currently on is always clear.

```js
if (document.body.classList.contains('index')){
 document.getElementById('nav-wwd').classList.add('selected');
}
if (document.body.classList.contains('approach')){
 document.getElementById('nav-oa').classList.add('selected');
}
if (document.body.classList.contains('about')){
 document.getElementById('nav-wwa').classList.add('selected');
}
if (document.body.classList.contains('insights')){
 document.getElementById('nav-oi').classList.add('selected');
}
if (document.body.classList.contains('contactus')){
 document.getElementById('nav-c').classList.add('selected');
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Comment: When you say that the code only works for a second, what do you mean? If the code snippet provided contains _all_ the code in `delayed.js` then your code only runs once and then finishes. There is no code to re-itterate the file/code

Comment: Hi T. Dirks, the 'selected' class I add to the HTML makes the nav item have a bottom border. When I don't have the JQuery script in my HTML page, the border is permanent. When I do, the border is present for a second, and then disappears. Not sure why!

Comment: That's quite strange. I tried to recreate your problem in JSFiddle but I couldn't reproduce the bug. Take a look at [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1z6youcg/) and let me know if I'm missing something

Comment: Thank you! Based on your Fiddle, I decided to recreate an HTML page from scratch to find the issue. It was occurring because I was drawing in a nav from another HTML page, as well as having one on the page itself, and the JS was only changing the code of the page itself. Problem solved!